# Why do I need to call UseSignalR before UseSpa in Startup Configure

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, single-page-application

I had a frustrating problem using SignalR in an .Net Core web application that was isusing Angular as a SPA. On SignalR negotiate from the client the web server would respond with a 404 error.

The exact issue and solution is described here in this GitHub issue. 
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2528

My question is, why is the order of calling UseSignalR and UseSpa important?
Why does this work and the web server accepts SignalR client communincations...

```
app.UseSignalR(routes => 
    { 
        ... 
    });

app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        ...
    });
```

and this configuration results in the web server responding with a 404

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        ...
    });

app.UseSignalR(routes => 
    { 
        ... 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaapplicationbuilderextensions.usespa?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for `SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseSpa`, you clearly see:

> Handles all requests from this point in the middleware chain by
>   returning the default page for the Single Page Application (SPA).
>
> This middleware should be placed late in the chain, so that other
>   middleware for serving static files, MVC actions, etc., takes
>   precedence.

So the `SpaMiddleware` catches **every** request that arrives to its point of the pipeline, and tries to handle it as a request to the SPA main page (Angular/React/other).

The order is always very important: ASP.NET Core uses a pipeline, so each middleware you put inside this pipeline is executed **in sequence**. If a middleware handles a request without calling the remaining part of the pipeline, then the request stops there and a response is returned.